# The order of evaluation of equality operator in C++

Tags: c++, equality, operator-precedence

Recently I have read some chapters C++ Primer, there is one things which made me confused.

The book says:

```
There are four operators that do guarantee the order in which operands are evaluated. 
the logical AND (&&) operator, 
the logical OR (||) operator, 
the conditional (? :) operator, 
and the comma (,) operator.
```

And then I saw these codes:

```
     if (val == true) { /* ... */ } // true only if val is equal to 1!
```

Then the book explain:

```
If val is not a bool, then true is converted to the type of val before the == operator is applied.
That is, when val is not a bool, it is as if we had written
     if (val == 1) { /* ... */ }
```

Here is my question:

Why is the bool type **true** converted to arithmetic type, not the **val** instead? Is it involve the order of evaluation of equality operator?

Just as the book says only four operators guarantee the order, not including equality operator. So the result of the expression above should be undefined, am I right? If not, what it should be?

Looking forward to your reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is related to the definition of C++ language. Study the [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) spec (i.e. read latest draft [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) ....)

Comment: You are confusing two very different things. `true` is converted to the type of the other argument because in arithmetic operators, the argument of the lesser rank is converted to the type of the other argument. It has nothing to do with the order of evaluation.

Comment: As presented (i.e. out of context), "If val is not a bool, then true is converted to the type of val before the == operator is applied." is not true *in general*, as `val` may be an instance of a class with an `operator bool() const` member that would then be compared to `true` without any integral conversions involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the order of evaluation. The comparison operators always perform the *usual arithmetic conversions* on their operands. These conversions apply equally to both operands (although the order is unspecified). In the case in which a `bool` is being compared to another integral type, the operand of type `bool` is always promoted to `int` first.

Answer (score 0):

Relational operators such as ==, <=, etc., always produce boolean results. This is part of a set of rules known as "the usual arithmetic conversions".

Which side of the operator gets converted to what and in what order is somewhat esoteric and would concern compiler writers. It would be beyond the scope of a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

In the condition of the if statement there are two different types
These are:

1. int
2. bool

In c++ types such as:

1. bool
2. char
3. short

are always converted to int first, hence in the condition of the if, true which is bool is converted to int and is 1 i.e, true is 1 and
 val remains the same.